# giblib error on LXterminal

Tags: scrot-command

I used this command:

```
scrot -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/Screenshots/
```

I have also created those folders in my directory but i cannot still take a screenshot. I keep getting:

```
giblib error:Saving to file filename.png failed
```

Comment: try writing  " cd .. " and yu will see the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a filename:

```
scrot test.png -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/Screenshots/'
```

or

```
scrot '%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/Screenshots/'
```